# SAS Compare Two Text Files (Unix / Windows)

Tags: sas, checksum, sas-macro

I need to compare two text files (in different directories) to see if they are different (a binary result is fine).  Given a dataset such as the one below, is this possible within a datastep?

```
Pathname
c:\one\text1.txt
c:\two\text1.txt
c:\one\text2.txt
c:\two\text2.txt
```

Alternatively, macro code would be fine! Checksum is a possibility, I need the code to run in both windows & unix.

Comment: If you can read the contents of the whole file into one variable, SAS has an `md5()` function you could use. But I'm not sure how to read a file that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it to the command line (via a pipe fileref)

In Windows, use the 'comp' command.

In Unix, use the 'diff' command.

Comment: How would you do this using SAS?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Chris J - this worked for me:

```
%let root=%sysfunc(pathname(work));
data;
file "&root.\x.txt";
put 'xxx';
data;
file "&root.\x2.txt";
put 'xx x';
filename x pipe "diff &root.\x.txt &root.\x2.txt ";
data;
infile x;
input x $1000.;
run;
```